# How do I print a Single item on a Array List

Tags: java, arrays, system.out

So I want to system print one of the names on my array list I was thinking it's like System.out.print(Names[1]) for the second item on my array list?

```
    System.out.println("How Many Employees On your Payroll");
    Employees = reader.nextDouble();

    ArrayList Names = new ArrayList();
    for (int i=1;i<=Employees;i++)
    {

        System.out.println("What is the name for Employee #"+i+"");
        String userName = userInputScanner.nextLine();
        Names.add(userName);


    }


    System.out.println("Do these Names Seem Correct?: " + Names);
```

Comment: Why do you think it would be `Names[1]`? _How do you get an element from a `List`_?

Comment: idk i just wanna print a single item , and the name of the array list is called "Names"

Comment: Don't do things if you don't know what you're doing. Research the proper way to do it.

Comment: I tried to research the best that I could but could not come up with anything.

Comment: @Brendanten You are using ArrayList, so one of the first research steps would be to read the documentation of ArrayList...

Comment: Also why Employees is a double? Can you have 2.5 employees on your payroll? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all try to obey Java code conventions:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

And to get the second element of the list use

```
names.get(1);
```

Where `names` is your list.

Comment: to print it in the terminal would I do names.get(1); or System.out.println(names.get(1))   sry im a noob programmer.

Comment: `System.out.println(names.get(1))`. In your particular case `System.out.println(Names.get(1))`, but try not to use first upper-case letter for variable namings. As this kind of namings is used for classes in common.

Comment: Thanks Alex that is totally what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is your friend. Use [`ArrayList#get(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29).

Answer (score 2):

First, ArrayList is a generic type so it's better to use ArrayList , for example:

```
 ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayLis<String> ();
```

Second,You can access the i'th number of an ArrayList (Say Names) by "get(int index)" method:

```
 Names.get(1)//to get the second items
```

Comment: everytime I try to use a .get() method on my ArrayList, it just returns gibberish. It doesn't return what Im actually looking for. How do I fix this?